# Accessing flask API from client side

Tags: python, rest, api, flask, server

I am new in creating API. But I created one like this code :

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def hello():
    try :
        with open('logs.txt','a') as f :
            f.write(f"{datetime.now()}\n")
    except Exception as e :
        print(str(e))
    value = request.args.get('symbol')
    result = database.get_symbol(value)
    return jsonify(result)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

So I have a VPS (Virtual private server) with windows7 on it and I am trying to run my flask app in it. but when I run it the code will be like this :

```
main.py:443: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  return webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option)
 * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

But when I run it in my server and trying to access it using my own personal computer with this code :

```
curl [ip_address]:5000/?symbol=value
```

it give me an error :

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to [IP] port 5000: Connection refused
```

How can people use this API?

can I just deploy it in developer mode?

Comment: try `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False)`

Comment: gave me the same problem

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1`  is your own IP address that can be accessed only from that PC.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False, host=<VPS's IP address>)
```

Instead of assigning, you can write `0.0.0.0`, and specify the VPS's IP address when connecting from outside.

Comment: I tried `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False)` and It didn't work

Comment: You CANT access by `http://0.0.0.0:5000/`. You should try to use the VPC's IP address with port 5000.

Comment: I know I used this : curl 188.40. 147.69:5000/?symbol=value